# count number of words between 2 fixed words

Tags: text-processing

I have a file as below

```
FHEAD
THEAD
TCUST
TITEM
TTEND
TTAIL
THEAD
TCUST
TCUST
TITEM
TITEM
TTEND
TTAIL
THEAD
TCUST
TITEM
TTEND
TTAIL
THEAD
TCUST
TCUST
TITEM
TTEND
TTAIL
```

I need to count thr  number of occurrence of ONLY TCUST records between THEAD and TTAIL where the occurrence is more than once and print that file name and line.

There will be multiple files so I need to print the filename as well.

Expected result is

THEAD
TCUST
TCUST
TITEM
TITEM
TTEND
TTAIL
THEAD
TCUST
TCUST
TITEM
TTEND
TTAIL
    name of file

Comment: What _line_ do you want to print? Or is it the line number? Of `THEAD`,  `TCUST` lines? Or the count of `TCUST` lines? Each count separately or as a total? An expected result would help.

Comment: Hi  Stéphane, Thanks for your reply. I want to find all occurrences of TCUST records where it is more than 1 between THEAD and TTAIL records, then print that line from THEAD to TTAIL (with more than 1 TCUST record)  and also print the filename

Comment: Hi Sundeep- expected result is           
THEAD
TCUST
TCUST
TTAIL 
THEAD
TCUST
TCUST
TTAIL

Comment: @Sundeep. Yes. I want to extract lines between THEAD and TTAIL if TCUST occurs more than once

Comment: can you clarify: 1) the last line should be name of input file? and should that be printed only if there was at least one matching section? 2) can there be lines not matching `TCUST` between `THEAD` and `TTAIL`?

Comment: @Sundeep. The last line should be name of input file and it should be printed if there is atleast one matching section.  There can be lines not matching TCUST between THEAD and TTAIL. I will edit the question and add these details for better understanding

Comment: Hi Sundeep, I have added details to the question. Hope if clarifies the requirement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk '
  /THEAD/{f=1; c=0; a = $0; next}
  f{a = a ORS $0; if(/TCUST/) c++}
  /TTAIL/{f=0; if(c > 1){print a; m=1} }
  ENDFILE{if(m) print FILENAME; m=0}
  ' ip.txt
THEAD
TCUST
TCUST
TITEM
TITEM
TTEND
TTAIL
THEAD
TCUST
TCUST
TITEM
TTEND
TTAIL
ip.txt
```

- `/THEAD/{f=1; c=0; a = $0; next}` starting pattern, set flag and initialize counter. Save current line for later printing
- `f{a = a ORS $0; if(/TCUST/) c++}` when flag is set, accumulate input lines in `a` variable and increment counter if line matches `TCUST`
- `/TTAIL/{f=0; if(c > 1){print a; m=1} }` ending pattern, clear flag. Print contents of `a` if counter is greater than `1`, also set variable `m` that at least one match is found
- `ENDFILE{if(m) print FILENAME; m=0}` after all lines are processed for a file, print input file name if `m` is set and clear before next file is processed (Thanks @Costas for pointing out multiple file requirement)

**Note:** `ENDFILE` is `GNU awk` specific, I am not sure how to handle it without `ENDFILE`

Thanks @Costas for solution not dependent on GNU specific`ENDFILE`:

```
$ awk '
  FNR==1{if(m) print fname; m=0; fname=FILENAME}
  /THEAD/{f=1; c=0; a = $0; next}
  f{a = a ORS $0; if(/TCUST/) c++}
  /TTAIL/{f=0; if(c > 1){print a; m=1} }
  END{if(m) print fname}
  ' *.txt
```

Comment: Hi Sundeep- Perfect.....works well !! Thanks for your help

Comment: Should add `FNR==1{m=0}` if several files

Comment: @Costas, thanks for pointing out fallacy for multiple files.. I have changed to `ENDFILE` which is `gawk` specific though..

Comment: For non-**GNU awk** you should add `FNR==1{if(m) print fname; m=0; fname=FILENAME}` altogether with `END{if(m) print fname}`

Comment: @ Sundeep - How to move the file (having multiple TCUST records) to some backup dir.. I am getting fatal division by 0 error

Answer (score 1):

By GNU sed the task can be done by

```
sed -sn '
    /THEAD/{:1;N;/TTAIL/! b1} #collect lines from `THEAD' to `TTAIL'
    /TCUST.*TCUST/{p;h}       #print if there are two TCUST and set hold
    ${x;//F}                  #check hold and output if two TCUST was in it
    ' file1 file2 …
```